# Rails: How to run code when server starts up, but not when running a rake task or the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, rake

Before, I added code to a file called `config/initializers/remote_publishers.rb` which set up a connection to RabbitMQ using the Bunny gem on server startup.

However, this is now also executed when running `rails c`, `rails g model SomeModel foo:integer`, `rails db:migrate` etc.

For this app, the RabbitMQ-connection only makes sense when rails is started using `rails s(erver)`.

What is the proper way to conditionally execute this code? Is there a way to see if Rails is starting as server, or only as task-runner?

Comment: Good question. I wonder if you and I simply made bad design decisions?

Comment: @codenoob Possibly, but I think it is not wrong to argue that Rail's design decisions sometimes lead to these kinds of situations, as (a) singletons are everywhere in Rails and (b) the way Rails starts up is rather magical/convoluted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What web server are you using? On Puma, for example, you can use

```
on_worker_boot do
  # Establish RabbitMQ connection
end
```

Another possibility might be to check `if defined?(Rails::Server)` in your initializer: this should only be true when running in the context of the web server.

Comment: Currently Puma, but of course a server-agnostic way to do this would be preferred!